# Apache handles 127.*.*.*:80 instead of just 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: apache-2.4

I'd like Apache to only handle requests to 127.0.0.1 so that I can use 127.0.0.2 etc. for other applications, so I've tried changing the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf to

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

and then I've restarted Apache, but it doesn't work. No other vhost rules are in place, output of `apachectl -S` is as follows:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:80           localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Comment: What `Listen` directives do you have?

Comment: ports.conf:
``Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Listen`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive is used to configure which address/port combinations that Apache httpd should bind to (or *listen* on, if you will).
When only a port is specified (no address), that means to bind to the specified port for all addresses.

The [`VirtualHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) directive, on the other hand, is part of the configuration for how to respond to requests (like what content to serve, etc).
The address/port that is specified in this context is used to select for which incoming requests that Apache httpd should even attempt to use this `VirtualHost`.

If you only want Apache httpd to only bind to `127.0.0.1:80`, you would do something like this as your only `Listen` directive:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining!